# troubles with object validation and assigning values

Tags: java, validation, object

So In this piece of code I'm going to post I'm trying to make it so that say you enter a bucket size of 3, Sense you picked the bucket size of 3 its suppose to make the value of the bucket bee 300$. when calculated in the rental profit method. But i've tried to arrange this code in many different ways but I cannot fix this problem. Can someone please give me some tips on how I should be doing this?

```
public void SetBucketSize(int b)
   { 

       if (bucket >6 || bucket <0)
       {
         System.out.println("Enter valid Bucket Size(1-5)");
       }

          if (bucket == 1)
          {

             BucketSize = 100;

          }
          if (bucket == 2)
          {

            BucketSize = 200;
          }
          if (bucket == 3)
          {

            BucketSize = 300;;
          }
          if (bucket == 4)
          {

            BucketSize = 400;
          }
          if (bucket == 5)
          {
            BucketSize = 500;
          }

        BucketSize = b;    
   }

public int GetBucketSize()
          {
             return this.BucketSize;
          }



@Override
    public int RentalProfit()  
    {
      return (RentalRate * RentalDays + BucketSize); 

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Does it throw a compile error? Or does it not calculate the value right? Please be more specific what kind of problem(s) you have.

Comment: You should use an array to store the candidate values for `BucketSize`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void SetBucketSize(int b) {
    if (b < 1 || b > 5) {
        System.out.println("Enter valid...");
        return;
    }
    BucketSize = b * 100;
}
```

Comment: Why change upper bound from 6 to 5? Either change it back to 6, or change lower bound to 1 as well.

Comment: I changed it to > 5 because it seemed to be what ried actually wants (judging by the error message). You're right about the zero. I missed that. Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would of never thought of this now looking back on this.

Answer (score 0):

`SetBucketSize` has a parameter named `b`, and does eventually execute `BucketSize = b`, but all the code before that is entirely wrong.

Guard condition allows values 0 to 6, but there is only `if` statements for value 1 to 5, so they don't cover 0 and 6 itself.

Also the code assigns to `BucketSize`, but that gets overridden by the final `BucketSize = b`, so in short, all the code is meaningless and does nothing.

I'm amazed that the code even compiles, because where does `bucket` even come from?